# Бесконечный RecyclerView с фиксированным кол-вом элементов

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, layoutmanager

Для примера можно привести "барабаны" для выбора даты.

[image: scr]

когда пользователь доходит до последнего элемента в списке месяцев например, после последнего ему сразу показывается первый. Или если листать в другую сторону, то после первого идет последний.

Т.е.:

obj2, obj3 ,obj4, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj1, obj2, obj3 и т.д

Comment: `getItemCount -> Integer.MAX_VALUE`. `getItem(position) -> items.get(position % items.size())`

Comment: @YuraIvanov а если в обе стороны?

Comment: При старте `scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)`. Ну и вам надо подогнать будет, чтоб это начальное значение делилось нацело на item.size(). Справитесь?

Comment: Вы же знаете, что `NumberPicker`, `DatePicker` и `TimePicker` основаны не на `RecyclerView` (`ListView`), а [на `LinearLayout`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java)?